# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context when I use Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, expression

I have method in my repository:

```
public ICollection<MyClass> GetAll(Expression<Func<MyClass,bool>> query)
    {
        return DbContext.MyTable.Where(query).ToList()
       //Error - Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context
    }
```

and the method that calls the repository(which throws an exception):

```
public MyMethod(List<MyClass> myList)
{
    Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> query = x => myList.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.Id);
    var list = repository.GetAll(query);
}
```

but this method does not throw an exception:

```
public MyMethod(List<MyClass> myList)
    {
        List<int> intList = myList.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
        Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> query = x => intList.Contains(x.Id);
        var list = repository.GetAll(query);
    }
```

I'm a beginner developer. Apparently not understand something. I want to understand. Who can help me?

Comment: do to list before Contains `Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> query = x => myList.Select(y => y.Id).ToList().Contains(x.Id);` Linq doesn't know how to translate the select from your c# objects

Comment: @LiviuBoboia Thanks for answer. But it don't work also.